# Cordova on iOS shows broken image

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova

I have a cordova app (cordova 5, ios 4) which uses Angular in the background.
I need to display an image (jpg) which I am downloading from my remote server via https.
However the image is always displayed as broken by the webview.
The image is included like this:

```
<img ng-src="{{picture}}">
```

I have tried 2 variants to include the picture:

- displaying the image directly via the https url. I can open the url in both a desktop browser and the iPhone Safari browser and they display it correctly. In cordova it is shown as broken
- downloading the image via File Transfer and then including the local image via a file:// link. Same problem.

What I have verified:

- the image itself is correct as I can show it in a browser
- the download itself works, the file transfer is correct
- cordova has been set to allow all resources so it does not seem to be a problem of whitelisting
- angulars sanitizing has also been adjusted so the links in the html are actually correct i.e. not modified
- the server is sending the correct content-type which I have verified via wget

I am running out of ideas here.

Comment: Verify filename is correct in `ng-src`. Case sensitively can sometimes be a issue in Cordova.

Comment: I get the filename directly from cordova so that can't be the problem. In both cases (filename, https) the Safari web inspector also tells me there was a problem loading the image. Unfortunately without further infos.

Comment: Can you post the exact error message?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the browser view of Cordova on iOS (UIWebview) is more strict than a standalone browser. I tried to download the image via wget and then had a look at the content. It did not show any jpg header but was identified as text by the unix file command.
The http headers also showed no Content-Length.

**Solution**
The server side logic (spring) returned a byte[] but I did not include any transformation to it. So I changed by rest configuration on the web app to include a ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter">
        </bean>         
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">              
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>    
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Then it worked. The browser seems to fix the missing file header and/or encoding (not sure what the exact error is) whereas the UIWebview doesn't do this.